# Include folder name in file name as part of a loop

Tags: powershell, loops, directory, rename

I try to get the directory name as part of a filename. The problem is that I want to do this for each file in a different separate folder, which does not seem to work.

What I have come to thus far is that I am able to get a list of subfolders ($GetAllActionTargetSubFolders) that each contain one or more files. In each of the subfolders, the files are combined into one file with the name 'temp'. Now, what does not work is, I want to rename this combined 'temp' file that is in each of the subfolders and want to include the subfolder name as such: FoldernameA_Consolidated202209161304.rpt (instead of temp.rpt)

I thought that the '$_.Directory.Name' would give me the directory name, but then I get this error message:

```
Rename-Item : Could not find a part of the path.
At line:5 char:125
+ ... de *temp* | Rename-Item  -NewName {$_.Directory.Name + "_Consolidated ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (\\networkdrive\R...ctions\temp.rpt:String) [Rename-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

This is the script that I have thus far:

```
#get a list of all sub directories:

$ActionTargetFolder = "\\networkdrive\2_ActionData_Prep\"
$GetAllActionTargetSubFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $ActionTargetFolder -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $true} 

#for each sub directory, make 1 file that contains all lines from the files that are in that specific sub directory:

ForEach ($foldername in $GetAllActionTargetSubFolders.FullName) {Get-ChildItem  $foldername -Recurse -File -Include *.rpt | get-content | sort | get-unique | Out-File -FilePath "$($foldername)\temp.rpt"-Force } 

#rename the 'temp' file that is created and include the sub-directory name, text and date/time:

ForEach ($foldername in $GetAllActionTargetSubFolders.FullName) {Get-ChildItem $foldername -Recurse -File -Include *temp* | Rename-Item  -NewName {$_.Directory.Name + "_Consolidated" + $((Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMddhhmm')) + ".rpt"}}
```

I hope someone could help me with this

Comment: Why don't you directly name the file correctly when you create it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Cid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73743930/include-folder-name-in-file-name-as-part-of-a-loop#comment130218816_73743930) already commented, there is no need to create a file with name `temp.rpt` first and rename it afterwards.

By naming the file as you want it straight away, you don't need that second loop.

Also, when using Get-ChildItem and want it to filter for just one extension, you should use `-Filter` instead of `-Include` because this works a lot faster.

Try:

```
# get a list of all sub directories:
$ActionTargetFolder = "\\networkdrive\2_ActionData_Prep\"
$GetAllActionTargetSubFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $ActionTargetFolder -Directory -Recurse

# for each sub directory, make 1 file that contains all lines from the files that are in that specific sub directory:
foreach ($folder in $GetAllActionTargetSubFolders) {
    # create the full path and filename for the output
    $outFile = Join-Path -Path $folder.FullName -ChildPath ('{0}_Consolidated_{1:yyyyMMddHHmm}.rpt' -f $folder.Name, (Get-Date))
    $content = $folder | Get-ChildItem -File -Filter '*.rpt' | Get-Content
    $content | Sort-Object -Unique | Set-Content -Path $outFile
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I had some trouble getting the date in the filename, so therefore I tried to add a second loop dedicated for renaming :). But if it is possible to do it all in one loop, that is even better!.

Comment: I tried the code above, but get an issue with the getdate and set content:       GetDate : The term 'GetDate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. Set-Content : Could not find a part of the path   (the subfolder name is now twice in the path)

Comment: @Hayco Yes, typo.. I missed the hyphen in `Get-Date`. Fixed now

Comment: of course! thanks. Only the set content now still returns an error: Set-Content : Could not find a part of the path  The path seems correct however: it shows the full path and the correct filename in the error message.

Comment: @Hayco Strange, that doesn't happen when I tested it.. Does your path perhaps use `[]` characters? In that case, try `Set-Content -LiteralPath $outFile`

Comment: no, my path does not use [] characters, it does include an & sign. I tried the LiteralPath, but it returns the same result:  Set-Content : Could not find a part of the path        + ...    $content | Sort-Object -Unique | Set-Content -LiteralPath $outFile
+                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\eubelccfs01\R...02209171535.rpt:String) [Set-Content], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentWriterDirectoryNotFoundError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand

Comment: it is the length of the path! it was in total 270 characters long (including the filename), if i shorten it, the script works! (max is probably 255 characters??).  Is it possible to enlarge the length of the total path or is the only way to use shorter folder/ filenames? Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @Hayco Good find! Depending on your OS, perhaps [Enable Long Paths in Windows 10, Version 1607, and Later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later) may help

Comment: Thank you. I am running version 5 of Powershell, the long path issue should be solved from version 7 and up. I will try to upgrade or else try to change the registry key in windows.